# Passive Infrared Sensors (PIR) spectrum and reflections

Tags: electrical-engineering, sensors, optics, lighting

I have a common PIR occupancy sensor (Lutron MS-OPS5M-WH). I am trying to get the sensor to cover an irregular-shaped room.

I could expand the field-of-view of the sensor to cover the whole room by installing a mirror so that the PIR sensor could "see" around a small corner. However, I need to know what material to make the mirror out of. I think standard soda-lime glass would reflect long-wave infrared, whether or not it's silvered, but it depends on the spectrum of light that these PIR sensor use.

Is this concept of using a mirror surface to let a PIR sensor see around corners a valid idea? And if so, what material does the mirror need to be made of?

Comment: Same stuff as a space blanket which is just aluminum. Worked in Predator 2, until it changed spectrums and killed everyone.

Answer (score 0):

Most metals should work. In my experience even tarnished metal looks like a mirror in IR. You should borrow someones FLIR camera to evaluate your setup, they're pretty common these days.